# Whitney and Tensor product structures on $BU$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a question regarding the 2 H-space structures on $BU$. My current understanding (which may not be correct!) is detailed below.

$BU$ admits two H-space structures described as follows:

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2$ be the universal $n$ and $m$ dimensional complex vector bundles respectively. Letting $\pi_1, \pi_2$, denote the projections from $BU(n) \times BU(m)$, we have the pullback bundles $\pi_1(\xi_1), \pi_2(\xi_2)$.

1) Taking the classifying map of the direct sum of these bundles yields a map $BU(n) \times BU(m) \to BU(n + m)$

2) Taking the classifying map of the tensor product of these bundles yields a map  yields a map $BU(n) \times BU(m) \to BU(nm)$

Passing these maps to colimits yields maps $BU \times BU \to BU$.

Now it is well known $\mathbb{Z} \times BU$ is a ring object in the homotopy category, $Ho$, and I was wondering what the structure maps are on this object.

My initial guess was that $\mathbb{Z}$ and $BU$ are both ring objects in $Ho$, and so $\mathbb{Z} \times BU$ would have the product ring object structure. However on p.201 of "A concise guide to Algebraic Topology" by J.P. May, it suggests that $BU$ is not a ring object, and "by fairly elaborate arguments, one can pass to colimits to obtain a ring structure on $\mathbb{Z} \times BU$".

My questions are as follows:

1) Is $BU$ a ring object in $Ho$?

2) How can one realise the ring object structure maps on $\mathbb{Z} \times BU$?

Any help appreciated.

Will

Comment: The second map does not induce a map on the colimit (not even on the homotopy colimit) per se, since the map does not not commute with the the stabilizing maps $BU(n)\rightarrow BU(n+1)$ as e.g. $(\zeta\oplus\epsilon)\otimes\eta$ is $(\zeta\otimes\eta)\oplus \eta$ and not $(\zeta\otimes\eta)\oplus \epsilon$, where $\zeta, \eta$ are bundles and $\varepsilon$ denotes the trivial line bundle.

Comment: Good spot, I hadn't noticed that. However I'm fairly sure that BU admits an H-space structure arising from the tensor product. Is there a route we can take to circumvent this issue?

Comment: There is a discussion about this on pg 205 of May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" (https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf).